# email forwarding in ISPConfig/dovecot instead of POP3

Tags: email, gmail, pop3

i have a server with dovecot and ISPConfig installed. Right now i have mailboxes, and using my gmail for fetching emails using pop3.
problem is google checks emails every X minutes.
i have a hotmail account, and emails from that account are forwarded directly to my gmail.

i want to set up something similar, that incoming emails will be forwarded immediately. i would set up a mail forward, but i still want the mailbox to exist on the server (for sending using SMTP). I want to avoid using google's mail server for managing my accounts under google apps. Just need incoming emails to be forwarded immediately.

How can this be done?

ps. i could think of an ugly idea to get it done - send a copy to my gmail account, and delete  incoming emails under pop3 using gmail. i'd prefer avoiding that too.

Answer (score 1):

Your local MDA probably supports something like `.forward` files, if you have a home directory on the server.  If you are using something else than Postfix / Exim / Qmail / Sendmail  (in vaguely descending order of weirdness), tell us what you do have.